# Text of same font and font size is two pixels off of each other

Tags: fonts, web-fonts

So I was writing an email and I was copying text from an older email because I sent mistyped the address the first time. I wrote the first line of the email before copying the text and I was about to delete it until I noticed something unsettling:

[image: wtf!!]

While all the letters are identical, there is an additional pixel of space before the *M* and the *h* in the first version – causing the rest of the line to be two pixels off.

Any idea why?

Comment: Hi Kevino, welcome to the site. That is strange, are you certain there's no whitespace character between the 'y' and 'M'? This question might be better suited for [su], though.

Comment: There's no whitespace between the y or the M on either line. I thought this'd be a good place to post since it seems like an issue with how the fonts are rendered? But I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't answer in this specific situation, the general answer to this question is that **not all applications will render the same font the same way**.

This that affect font rendering include anti-aliasing, kerning, and DPI. There may also be a difference between how an application renders a font on screen vs how it is printed. Try browsing a few web pages in Firefox and Chrome side-by-side; you'll see that each render fonts their own way.

Similar question: [Why is GIMP rendering fonts differently than other applications](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63080/why-is-gimps-rendering-fonts-differently-than-other-applications)